# Gon doesn't work with .js files in Sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra

In my `head` within `layout.erb` I included `<%= include_gon %>`

In `main.rb` I have written

```
require 'gon-sinatra'
Sinatra::register Gon::Sinatra

gon.test = "Test"
puts gon.test
```

The console outputs `Test` as expected.

However when I create a .js file and write something like `console.log(gon.test)` and I look in Firebug or Chrome Console, it says `Reference Error: gon is not defined`. Why is this happening? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you  `<%= include_gon %>`?

Comment: Yes, as you can see I have written in the first sentence :)

Comment: And what do you see in your `<head>` in the rendered `HTML`?

Comment: I feel really stupid. I checked for the rendered `HTML` and saw `<script></script>` with nothing in it. Turns out that I have written in `layout.erb` `<script><%= include_gon%></script>`. Thanks for opening my eyes. :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have written `<script><%= include_gon %></script>` which makes it fail. `<%= include_gon %>` shouldn't be written inside `<script>` tags.